# How to ignore if line already exists in writing file in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have file1.txt which contains lines as

```
list 0
list 1
line 1
```

In file2.txt i want to write only if the line is not already exists in file2.txt

my code:

```
fo=open("file1.txt","r")
fin=open("file2.txt","a")
lines=fo.readlines()

for line in lines:
    if "list" in line:
       fin.write(line)

for line in lines:
    if "li" in line:
       fin.write(line)
```

Output: It is printing the lines twice.Here I want to write only once if the same line is repeated.

```
list 0 
list 1    
list 0    
list 1    
line 1
```

My output should be

```
list 0   
list 1    
line 1
```

Comment: Use a dictionary where you save all lines you already read. before you write a line into your file, check whether it is in the dict or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be, to first read all lines of `file2.txt` and put them into a suitable datastructure (i.e. a `Set`).
Then reopen `file2.txt` in append mode, iterate over all lines of `file1.txt` and write only these that are not in the set (here, the `in` operator comes handy...)

```
with open("file2.txt", "r") as f2:
  lineset = set(f2)

with open("file2.txt", "a") as f2:
  with open("file1.txt", "r") as f1:
    for line in f1:
      if not line in lineset:
        d2.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will read all the lines in file2 and only write a line to file2 if its not already there. It will also close your file automatically by using the excellent "with" statement in python. :)

```
with open("file1.txt","r") as file1, open("file2.txt", "w+") as file2:
    lines2 = file2.readlines()
    for line in file1:
        if line not in lines2:
            file2.write(line)
```

If you want to use list iteration, the same code is just 2 lines, but I prefer the readability of the first version.

```
with open("file1.txt", "r") as file1, open("file2.txt", "w+") as file2:
    [file2.write(line) for line in file1 if line not in file2.readlines()]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a set to track the collection of lines in the `file2.txt` file.

```
fo=open("file1.txt","r")
fin=open("file2.txt","a")
lines=fo.readlines()
# Rewing the file so that we can read it's contents.
fin.seek(0)
existing_lines = set(fin)

for line in lines:
    if line not in existing_lines:
       fin.write(line)
       existing_lines.add(line)
```

Answer (score -1):

You would want to do something like:

```
fo=open("file1.txt","r")
fin=open("file2.txt","a")
linesOut=fo.readlines()
linesIn=fin.readlines()

for lineOut in linesOut:

    #check each line in linesIn to see if it contains lineOut
    writeLine=True
    for lineIn in linesIn:
        if lineOut==lineIn:
            writeLine=False

    #if not add it
    if writeLine:
        fin.write(lineOut)
```